# HTML TD and passing TD onclick

Tags: html

I want to be able to click on a table data, once I've clicked it, it should then store what is inside that table data into a variable that I can use.

ex. `TD="1234" OnClick AX="1234"`

```
display=AX
conduct search=AX
```

etc

still a beginner so not sure how to make certain tags/code work with each other

```
<table id="detail_table" class="detail">  
    <thead>  

    <tr>  
    <th>ID</th>  
    <th colspan="2">Name</th>  
    </tr>  
    </thead>  
    <tbody>  
    <tr class="parent" id="row101" title="Click to expand/collapse" 
    style="cursor: pointer;">  
    <td>101</td>  
    <td colspan="2">File Management Tool</td>  
    </tr> 

    <tr class="child-row101" style="display: none;">  
    <td> </td>  
    <td>New File Tool</td>
    </tr>  

    <tr class="child-row101" style="display: none;">  
    <td> </td>  
    <td>Transfer Report</td>  
    </tr>
```

From the sample code, what I want to achieve is if I click on one of the child tds (Ex: *File Management Tool*) I want that info stored in a variable (AX= *File Management Tool*), which I can then pass on to another form to conduct a search.

Is this doable?

Many thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: used this script with the above code:

Comment: It's absolutely possible, and you would need JavaScript to do it. Or make use of a `<form>` and `POST` if you want the data stored in a server-side variable.

Comment: I've actually got a script but I cant post here for some reason, giving me an error message :(

Comment: @MasatoIndou Try to put the relevant parts of the script into the question itself.